# Styling heading with a line

Tags: html, css

In a way this is simple but I have been trying to figure out this for hours now so I decided to write the problem down and maybe with your help I could find a solution.

On layout heading (h1, h2, h3) have a line next to them. Basically somehting like this:

Example Heading--------------------------------------------

Another Example Heading---------------------------------

One more------------------------------------------------------

So that is end result (----- is gfx as background-image). How would you do it? The background color could change and/or have opacity.

One thing what I was thinking would be this:

```
<h1><span>Example Heading</span></h1>
```

when the CSS would look lke this:

```
h1 {
background-image: url(line.png);
}
h1 span {
background: #fff;
}
```

But since the background color can be something else than white (#fff) that doesn't work.

Hopefully you did understand my problem :D

Comment: Is `Example Heading------------------` something you already have or something you want to build into?

Comment: Something what I want to achieve yes.

Comment: That's a really interesting question. The only thing that's springing to my mind at the moment is maybe using `display: table-cell` in some way, but it seems a bit nasty.

Answer (score 2):

Hacky but, maybe something like this:

HTML:

```
<h1>
    <span>Test</span>
    <hr>
    <div class="end"></div>
</h1>
```

And the css:

```
h1 span{ float :left; margin-right: 1ex; }
h1 hr {
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top:0.5em;
}
h1 div.end { clear:both; }
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zftSc/2/)

Comment: Quick and dirty for the win !

Comment: Not pretties one but works! And I think this might be the only way to do it without JS.

Comment: Yup. It's not lovely, but at least it's pure CSS and should be pretty cross-browser friendly, from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

HTML

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="title1">TITLE</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.title {
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
.title .title1 {
    width: 125px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -12px
}
```

Comment: There's background color #fff on class title1. The actual background of the title can be white, some gredient, gray so title1 can't have any background color, it should be transparent. Basically this is same what I tried before, but cuomplex version of it tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this with pure css because the heading text could be any length. Here is a dynamic javascript solution which sets the width of the line image based on the width of the heading text.

[Click here for jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g4aMk/)

html (can be h1, h2 or h3)

```
<div class="heading-wrapper">
    <h1>Example Heading</h1>
    <img src="line.png" width="193" height="6" alt="" />
</div>
```

css

```
h1{font-size:16px}
h2{font-size:14px}
h3{font-size:12px}
h1,h2,h3{margin:0;padding:0;float:left}
.heading-wrapper{width:300px;overflow-x:hidden}
.heading-wrapper img{
    float:right;padding-top:9px;
    /*ie9: position:relative;top:-9px */
}
```

jquery

```
setHeadingLineWidth('h1');
setHeadingLineWidth('h2');
setHeadingLineWidth('h3');

function setHeadingLineWidth(selector){
    var hWidth;
    var lineWidth;
    var wrWidth = $('.heading-wrapper').width();

    hWidth = $(selector,'.heading-wrapper').width();
    lineWidth = wrWidth - hWidth;
    $(selector).siblings('img').width(lineWidth);
}
```

- heading width = width of the heading text inside the wrapper
- line image width = wrapper width - heading text width

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, this is one way to go but I think ill go with dirty HTML and CSS what 32bitkid provided.